# How to link the backend admin code to front end in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, frontend, backend

I have created an admin panel with the backend functionalities for a website and now, I have to link that to the frontend design. How could I do that? I know I have to create a frontend controller but after that how to link that with website design? can anyone help me out this is the first project I am trying to do?

I need to populate the course code with the frontend. How do I call the query?

course code for backend admin panel:

```
class CoursesController < AdminController
 before_action :set_course, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def index
  @courses = Course.all
 end

 def show
 end

def new
 @course = Course.new
end

def edit
end

def create
 @course = Course.new(course_params)
 respond_to do |format|
  if @course.save
   format.html { redirect_to @course, notice: 'Course was successfully 
   created.' }
   format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @course }
  else
   format.html { render :new }
   format.json { render json: @course.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity 
  }
  end
 end
end

def update
 respond_to do |format|
  if @course.update(course_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @course, notice: 'Course was successfully 
 updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @course }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @course.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity 
  }
  end
 end
end

def destroy
 @course.destroy
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to courses_url, notice: 'Course was successfully 
  destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end

private
 def set_course
   @course = Course.find(params[:id])
 end

 def course_params
   params.require(:course).permit(
    :title,
    :alias,
    :start_date,
    :end_date,
    :max_participants,
    :min_participants,
    :course_fee,
    :tax,
    :deposit,
    :description,
    :category_id,
    :location_id,
    :short_description,
    :currency,
    :if_fully_booked,
    course_ids: []
    )
  end
 end
```

I also have frontend code for admin panel which is written in course.html.erb file. But I have a separate view for frontend website design. how do I link that code to the backend?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your code, you are responding in two formats:

- HTML (format.html)
- JSON (format.json)

So, if you write in your browser something like: localhost:3000/courses.json (extension .json is important), you should receive a json response.

If you don't know how cosume a json with javascript, you will need to study about it.

More information in

- [ActionController::MimeResponds](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html)
- [Using Rails for API-only Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response.. ill look at the info